# Can't see docker image of Secure Registry by tag

Tags: docker, http-status-code-404, docker-registry

I have a CI-server which is building en pushing images to a secure registry. Every image gets a tag which is equal to the ID of the build.
I can see the images in my secure registry (self-signed). I can also use them so they're working fine.

But I'm unable to see them by URL in my browser:
In the browser of the server I'm performing:

```
https://localhost:5000/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/conti/myapp/_manifests/tags/19
```

But I'm getting a 404-error instead of the image ID (after I've accepted the certificate).

What am I doing wrong? I get a 404 for every https://localhost:5000/...
I see nothing when just going to https://localhost:5000

```
[x@localhost ~]$ curl -k https://localhost:5000/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/conti/myapp/_manifests/tags/19
404 page not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker registry V2 doesn't support that particular endpoint, so it's not possible at the moment.